# Why View Debugger missing in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, view-debugging

Running old Objective-C project in Xcode 8. Xcode does not show `View Debugger` on my machine, friend of my has it, with same project. What is required to have `View Debugger`?

Comment: Which iOS version are you running on the simulator or device (not the build SDK)? I believe there's a minimum of iOS 8 or 9.

Comment: I set `Deployment target` to the most recent `10.2` Though `View Debugger` button not able to see.